# Node Buffer to javascript array with offset

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert a node Buffer to a Uint8ClampedArray, but I want to discard the first 8 bytes. I tried like this:

```
buf = new Buffer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);
arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(buf, 8, 8);
```

But it appears as though the offset is ignored, `arr` contains all of `buf`.

How can I convert `buf` to an array beginning at an offset of *n* bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Buffer.slice`:

```
> arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(buf.slice(8));
Uint8ClampedArray [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ]
```

By the way, constructing your `Buffer` this way is deprecated:

```
> buf = new Buffer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);
<Buffer 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10>
[DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and 
usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or 
Buffer.from() methods instead.
```